# Save command string into bash variable

Tags: shell-script

I'm running a command like so, with the `$OUTPUT` variable saving the results of the command. But I also want to save the command itself to a variable for inclusion in a status email.

```
OUTPUT=$(php -f $LOCATION/somefile.php -- -process "$INPUTFILE" 2>&1)
```

The first part works. Then I tried this:

```
IMPORTCOMMAND='php -f' "$LOCATION"'/somefile.php -- -process'"$INPUTFILE"
```

But instead of saving the string to the variable, it seems to be just executing the command a second time.

EDIT:

Here is a mockup of how I create my email body. I have single quotes around regular strings and then double quotes around bash variables.

```
BODY='<b color="red">Output:</b><br />'"$OUTPUT"'<b color="red">Command:</b> '"$IMPORTCOMMAND"
```

After that I try to replace newlines with html "
" like so:

```
BODY="${BODY//$'\n'/<br />}"
#changed $BODY="" to BODY="" per yaegashi's suggestion
```

The following error disappeared after I followed yaegashi's suggestion:

```
/usr/local/bin/some-script.sh: line 59: <b: command not found
```

But the original error remains, at the `IMPORTCOMMAND` variable assignment.

Comment: You need to double quote `"$IMPORTCOMMAND"` when using it.

Comment: @cuonglm thanks for the hint. I did double quote it when I assigned it to my `$BODY` variable. It seems like the error occurs when I try to replace newlines with `<br />`. Please see my edit.

Comment: You should do like `BODY="..."`.  No heading `$`.

Comment: @yaegashi I'm getting an error at the line `IMPORTCOMMAND='php -f' "$LOCATION"'/somefile.php -- -process'"$INPUTFILE"` line. The php script is being executed. I must be doing something wrong with the quotes up there.

Comment: just a matter of spacing; I think you want something like: `IMPORTCOMMAND='php -f '"$LOCATION"'/somefile.php -- -process '"$INPUTFILE"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have too many quotes and in the wrong places.

The following will try run `somefile.php` and not set IMPORTCOMMAND as there is a space between `php -f` and `somefile.php.`

```
IMPORTCOMMAND='php -f' "$LOCATION"'/somefile.php -- -process'"$INPUTFILE"
```

Should be:

```
import_command="php -f $LOCATION/somefile.php -- -process $INPUTFILE"
output=$( ${import_command} 2>&1 )
```

OR (if 'LOCATION' or 'INPUTFILE' contain spaces)

```
import_command=( php -f "$LOCATION/somefile.php" -- -process "$INPUTFILE" )
output=$( "${import_command[@]}" 2>&1 )
```

And display it:

```
BODY="<b color='red'>Output:</b><br />${output}
      <b color='red'>Command:</b>     ${import_command[*]}"
```

Comment: The space after `'php -f'` was indeed the problem. You and Jeff Schaller are correct. `$LOCATION` and `$INPUTFILE` are both file paths with no spaces, but it's good to know how to handle spaces for future reference. Thank you.